# Ошибка TypeError, не понял в чем проблема

Tags: python

```
lines = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    with open ("text.txt", "w") as logg:
        logg.write(lines=+1)
        logg.write(datetime.datetime.now())
        logg.close()
```

Данный код выдает такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: TextIOWrapper.write() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: Что вы собственно хотите? `log.write(str(lines)); lines += 1`  будет работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исходя из [синтаксиса](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/metody-fajlovogo-obekta-potoka-python/metod-file-write/) команды `write`, она может принимать лишь один аргумент — строку, которая будет записываться в некоторый файл. Вы же пытаетесь увеличить значение `lines` на 1, сделав так, будто бы `lines` есть один из аргументов функции `write`, что, как я уже написал выше, не так.

Более того, Вы почему-то пишете `lines=+1`, что **присваивает** переменной единицу, а не увеличивает её на 1. Для увеличивания используется `+=`, если что.

Уберите строку `logg.write(lines=+1)` и вместе неё запишите `lines += 1` — тогда программа должна будет заработать.

```py
lines = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    with open ("text.txt", "w") as logg:
        lines += 1
        logg.write(datetime.datetime.now())
        logg.close()
```